# Is it possible to get the size of a variable in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

While debugging a C program in Visual Studio 2008, is it possible somehow to get the size of variables (in bytes)?

P.D. Of course I can print sizeof(var) for each of them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the **[Immediate Window](http://coliveira.net/software/using-the-immediate-window-on-visual-studio/)** to evaluate `sizeof(...)` or any other expression while debugging.

Comment: For `sizeof(Type)` I got "Error: argument list required for member function" while debugger was stopped inside `Type`. Solution: explicitly specify the namespace of the type. sizeof() also works in the watch window.

Comment: I get 0 when using the immediate window, but non zero when assigning to a temporary variable.  Any idea?